# How does React State Hook gets the state variable name from the ES6 Destructuring Assignment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, destructuring

In React [State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), one can write the following line to set a state variable called `count` and the `setCount` function to set the value afterwards, like below:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

Which is going to be the equivalent of writing:

```
this.state = { count: 0 };
```

My question is, how does the `useState()` function can get the name of the state variable -- `count` in this case, from the ES6 Destructuring Assignment statement?

Isn't the *destructuing* happens after the function has returned its value? Or is it possible to dynamically get the values that are being destructed, inside the function when it is invoked?

**Update**

Please note that I do understand that I can deconstruct to any name that I want, but how does the `useState()` knows what variable should go in the *state*, so it can be used later.

For example if I set two state variables, how does it distinguish between the two values, if the `useState()` function is not aware of the variable names?

```
const [age, setAge] = useState(42);
const [fruit, setFruit] = useState('banana');
```

Comment: You can read [this blog post](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2019/03/11/deep-dive-how-do-react-hooks-really-work/) to get an understanding of how hooks work under the hood

Comment: @Tholle I think that's what I was exactly looking for!

Answer (score 3):

When you use functional-components and useState

```
const [myCountVariable, setCount] = useState(0);
```

You only access your data using the myCountVariable variable. this.state isn't used.

If I understand correctly what you didn't understand is how it knows to write into 'this.state.myCountVariable' - it doesn't. The state doesn't store with the actual variable name.

Like the posts above me said, the useState assumes each time the component calls it it will call it in the same order so it returns "variable holders" based on index.

In React docs you can see they reference this in React Hook Rules:

> Only Call Hooks at the Top Level
>   Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth below.)

Basically,

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
```

is more accurately represented as

```
componentStateContainer[currentStateIndex] = myStateVariable; //React doesn't know how you named your local variable
currentStateIndex++;
return [myStateVariable, setStateMethod]
```

(currentStateIndex will reset to 0 when the function component is re-created)

Answer (score 1):

It's returning an array that you destruct. The first index of the array is the value, the second the function. With array destructuring you can set a name for those variables

Example:

```js
const [one, two] = ["test", () => {console.log(1)}];
console.log(one) // would be test
two() // would print out 1
```

More here:
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/array-destructuring-in-es6-30e398f21d10

Answer (score 1):

`useState` returns an array, where first element is the value and second is the setter and using `de-structuring` you can give any name to it

For instance the above code is equivalent to

```
const state = useState(0);
const count = state[0];
const setCount = state[1];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please have a look at my updated question.

Comment: So, the order is important here, right? The state would be an array then? How would it work if we had more than one state variable then?

Comment: It doesn't matter that the type of data in useState is, first element of returned array is the state and second is the setter. If state is an object, first element will be an object

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I was talking about setting multiple state variables, like the one that is my updated section. but I guess I have now found the answer. thanks!

Comment: @Mahdi consider accepting the answer it answer your question

Comment: Hi, unfortunately it doesn't fully answer my question. I found my answer in the link that @Tholle had put in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Destructuring of arrays in JS is done by index, not by property name. Only the destructuring of objects is by property name.

Answer (score 0):

As shared before on past answers you can see how the return is named by the array destructuring:

> More here:
> https://medium.freecodecamp.org/array-destructuring-in-es6-30e398f21d10

At the useState hook you are naming the function return:

```
function customFunction(){
   let var
   
   function setVar(value) {
      var = value
   }
   return [ var, (value) => setVar(value) ]
}
```

Using the array destructuring you are able to define a custom name for each array element by position.

```
const [ myCustomVar, setCustomVar ] = customFunction()
```

Comment: var is a reserved keyword in javascript so I would change var to something else. It will probably not work if you use it

Comment: needs renaming of `var` variable to non reserved keyword